# How do I implement routing in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm new to React and I'm having issues implementing routing. I think I have everything set up but when I try routing,  the components I import display on the index page yet I should see a new page.

I tried to define all paths and importing the required components

**My Sign Up Component**

```
export const SignUp = () => (

    <Container>
        <h2>Sign Up</h2>
        <Form className="form">
            <Col>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Label>First Name</Label>
                    <Input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="firstName" 
                        id="firstName" 
                        placeholder="First name..."
                    />
                     <Label>Second Name</Label>
                    <Input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="secondName" 
                        id="secondName" 
                        placeholder="Second name..."
                    />
                     <Label>Email</Label>
                    <Input 
                        type="email" 
                        name="email" 
                        id="email" 
                        placeholder="Email..."
                    />
                </FormGroup>
            </Col>
            <Button>Submit</Button>
        </Form>
    </Container>
)
```

**My App.js File**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Layout} from './components/Layout'; 
import { NavigationBar} from './components/NavBar'
import {Footer} from './components/Footer';
import {SignUp} from './components/Signup'; 
import { SignIn} from './components/Signin';
import { Home } from './components/Home';
class App extends React.Component {

  render(){
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <NavigationBar/>
        <Layout> 
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact  path="/"/>
            <Route  path="/signup" component={SignUp}/>
            <Route  path="/signin" component={SignIn}/>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
         <Footer/>
        </Layout>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

I really expect to first type the path in the address bar before using links and get to the imported component(page)

Comment: Are you trying to use BrowserRouter from `react-router-dom`? or Router from `react-router-dom`. Could you add all imports, that will be useful to find out what your problem is.

Comment: Hi @AlejandroGarciaAnglada, take a look at my edited post. It shows all the imports now. Thanks

Comment: The router part looks good to me. Could you elaborate on this part of your question: "the components I import display on the index page yet I should see a new page"? Do you mean you didn't expect to see a page refresh? Or did the component display incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to get a result from requesting `/`, but nothing comes up.

I elaborated an example for you, with similar code in codesandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/vibrant-paper-knmqj

The problem I can see is that you need to pass the `Home` component to the `/` route.

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
```

Hope my example helps.

Comment: Hi Alejandro & Claire, thanks for your input and probing questions. I came to realize that I was importing and passing the Home component but I didn't really customize it because I was using the styles from index.css  which affected the whole app.